# Mobile not showing comments on deleted answers

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers, mobile-web

<s>I don't know if this applies to all deleted answers (I didn't have time to check ;)),</s> (see edit) but at least some of them don't show comments on the mobile website. As an example [take this one](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4796/8478) (only visible to mods and high-rep users on CodeGolf.SE).

On desktop:

[image]

On mobile:

[image]
<sup>Click for larger version.</sup>

I believe these should be shown - even if it's not a common use case (apparently, because I couldn't find this bug being reported before), just because not showing content that actually exists sounds like a bug to me. (And I actually, I did notice it because I knew the answer had comments which I wanted to read.)

**Edit:** After ProgramFOX's comment, I had another look, and it seems that the comments are only missing if all of them are collapsed by default. On the same question as the above link, I can see the comments of all answers, where at least one comment has been upvoted (such that not all of them are collapsed).

To reproduce here on MSE:

1. Go to [this deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/236983#236983) (note the "show 1 more comment" in there)
2. Click "mobile" link in footer
3. No "show 1 more comment" thus no way to see the comment.

Comment: Weird, for that answer the comments don't show up on mobile, but for another deleted answer, I can see the comments.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Thank for checking it. I've had another look and it seems that it's only missing if all comments are collapsed by default. I'll update the question.

Comment: No repro on Stack Overflow, where it shows 5 comments before collapsing.

Comment: Found such answer here, added to the post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you.